# ListView and Database

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am trying to display a database content using ListView from an .mdf database file. Here is the block of code I am using:

```
        connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        DataTable table;
        SqlCommand command;

        command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM movies", connection);
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        table = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        moviesListView.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

And this is not working. I have also tried DataContext instead of ItemsSource, but it does not help. When I am using DataGrid, on the other hand, it work fine.

Could you please explain the reason for that?

Regards,
Vitalii.

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get an exception or error message?

Comment: Just don't see the content (the ListView is empty).

Comment: Stupid question: but, did you checked whether `table` actually contains any rows?

Comment: Yes, `table` contains correct columns and rows.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this one, and it worked for me:

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="osmanGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="243,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tid}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Acceleration" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Acceleration}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Background class:

```
try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Osman\Documents\osmanDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
            {

                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapvare = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM osmanTable", con);
                System.Data.DataSet dsFald = new System.Data.DataSet();
                adapvare.Fill(dsFald, "osmanTable");
                osmanGrid.DataContext = dsFald.Tables["osmanTable"].DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As I said, DataGrid works OK. I was wondering about ListView.

Comment: Just change your sql table name and connection string. Also the name of your table columns you have to bind to (DisplayMemberBinding)